# Pulso space varias veces y mi personaje no salta cada vez que lo pulso

Tags: c#, unity3d

Cuando pruebo este código, mi personaje salta de vez en cuando, no cada vez que pulso "space". Si pulso "space" 5 veces, el personaje salta solo 1 vez, ¡no sé por qué! Hay veces que incluso no salta.

```
public float speed;
public float fuerzaSalto = 5;

private Rigidbody rb;


void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();     
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") )
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, fuerzaSalto,0), ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Estas usando los input en el método fixedUpdate, que se ejecuta cada cierto segundos (normalmente 0.02). Es mejor que uses para los input el `update` que se ejecuta una vez por cada cambio de frame.

Comment: Gracias! Lo he puesto en el Update y salta perfectamente cada que pulso space...ahora incluso vuela! Tendré q poner una booleana para q reconozca el suelo! Muchas gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Por una cuestión de que el `FixedUpdate` es el método que se adapta a la cantidad de fotogramas mostrados y no a los transcurridos, lo que está pasando es que: supongamos tu juego esta corriendo a 100 fps y el monitor solo puede mostrar 60 frames, si estás verificando en `FixedUpdate` habrá 40 frames en los que se podría haber presionado un botón pero no se registrará.

La opción más óptima para solucionar algo así es pasar la información de teclas presionadas de `Update()` para luego ser presionadas en `FixedUpdate()`. **A continuación cómo hacerlo por medio de un enumerador.**

```
public enum KeyState { Off, Down, Hold, Up }

/// DATOS ///

private RigidBody rb;
public float fuerzaSalto = 5;
public KeyState space = KeyState.Off;

/// DATOS ///

/// METODOS ///

private void CheckKey(out KeyState kState, KeyCode kCode)
{
   if(Input.GetKeyDown(kCode))
   {
      kState = KeyState.Down;
   }
   else if(Input.GetKey(kCode))
   {
      kState = KeyState.Hold;
   }
   else if(Input.GetKeyUp(kCode))
   {
      kState = KeyState.Up;
   }
   else
   {
      kState = KeyState.Off;
   }
}

void Awake()
{
   rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
}

void Update()
{
   CheckKey(out space, KeyCode.Space);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
   if(space.Equals(KeyState.Down))
   {
      rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, fuerzaSalto, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
   }
}

/// METODOS ///
```